# How to write a php code so that I can create a link like this "http://website/2017/name.html"

Tags: php, html

I'm sorry that my question itself is not the way it should be. I am new to php and the links to open a post ( let's take that I am creating a website something like a blog ) is like open.php?id=sth 
I have seen in blogger and many other sites the links to open a post is in the type I have given in the question head. I would like to know how this is done. Is this in a way by which they create a directory and make an html file  (as in the example) in that particular directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a ".htaccess" file and [apache url rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).You don't need to create a directory.

Create a ".htaccess" file on the root folder and add something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) ./open.php?params=$1 [L]
```

This will make your url like "http://example.com/2017/name"

You can debug your parameters with that code:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Answer (score -1):

open.php?url=http://example.com

```
<?php
header('Location: '+urldecode($_GET['url']);
?>
```